# "errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR","message":"Non-static method requires a target."

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi

I am trying to create an envelope using E-signature post API from AppScript. I am able to Authenticate and call other Get API's like Status of Envelope and List of all envelopes successfully. But for this Post API I am facing below error.

```
"errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
"message":"Non-static method requires a target."
```

here is the object which I am passing

```
var createEnvelopeObj = 
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "JVBERi0----------DI0NGItMThmMzAtNS41LjEzLVNOQVBTSE9UCnN0YXJ0eHJlZgoxOTY2MDcKJSVFT0YK",
      "documentId": "1323457",
      "fileExtension": ".pdf",
      "name": "sampledoc"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Please sign below Document ref: G654sfd238",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "email": "xxxx@dddd.com",
        "name": "xxxx",
        "recipientId": "124",
        "routingOrder": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
};
```

Below is the API call with above object

```
function DocusignPost(createEnvelopeObj){
var options = {
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxO___xxxxx_VKdnH4FHUtI80s5xtZ9tusnP1DmYw '
    },
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(createEnvelopeObj),
    'muteHttpExceptions': true};
try{
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxx/envelopes", options );

  var postresponce = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log("postresponce : " + JSON.stringify(postresponce));
  return postresponce;}catch(exp){
Logger.log(exp);  }}
```

I have referred both these 57258880, 35047127 but I am using latest Auth method and passing object as payload, but still facing an issue.
Request someone to look into this and shed some light on it. I got stuck here for a couple of days.

Comment: what lang are you using? Node.js/Javascript? Is there a line number/stacktrace for the error? do you actually see it coming from DocuSign? can you use fiddler to check? get the full response you get?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in your JSON. So the next step I recommend is to obtain the API trace from DocuSign to see exactly what is being received from DocuSign.

See https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

You should also carefully check how you're reading in the PDF file before base64 encoding it. PDF files are (almost always) binary, so you need to read them using a binary-clean method.